# How do I capture search index in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I do have table `table1` with two columns say `name` and `details` when I search by `details` there were multiple name listing. I want to retrieve that name list and display to a webpage using PHP. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most basic page.php:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE details = "something"');
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  array_push($result,$row['name']);
  echo $row['name'].'<br />';
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: if I need to catch whole in implode function then??

Comment: I dont quite understand - do you want to store all of the values in an array and then implode them?

Comment: It's the same as doing `$result[] = $row['name']`